# Sed Conditional Multiline Change

Tags: sed

I need to make some changes in a large group of files but the condition for if the change is to be made is based on what is on the previous line:

Example:

```
<element1>
  <value>true</value>
```

In this case I want to make the change to the line true

But if it is a case such as:

```
<wrong_element>
  <value>true</value>
```

Then I do not want it changed.

I can get sed to make the change but it changes all values.
I can also get it to ignore white spaces as different files might have a different number of white spaces

I read sed reads and evaluates based on lines, how can I make the change based on what is on a previous line?

Comment: If it's HTML, what happens if the tags shown up on the same line, or separated by a comment-line? Parsing HTML line-wise is fragile.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the sort of thing that 'awk' is really good at instead of 'sed':

```
cat file | awk 'BEGIN {lastLINE="XXX";} \
        { if ( lastLINE ~ /element1/ ) gsub(/BADtextREGexpression/,"replaceTEXT") ; printf("%s\n",$0); lastLINE = $0; }'
```

If there are no bugs, the above will print out all lines unchanged, unless the last line had a piece that matched the regular expression "element1".  In that case it will make a global substitute of "replaceTEXT" into the current line (in place of BADtextREGexpression) before printing.

$0 is a variable representing the current whole line just read from the input file and is the default target of gsub().

I don't know how to do it if 'sed' is absolutely required.
Link to an online 'awk' manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html